# Black screen Unity AR Foundation - camera not working

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, camera, screen, augmented-reality

Cannot use the camera for an AR Unity App.

When launching the app on an iOS device, the screen is totally black.

I'm running Unity version 2021.3

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions could be:

- Go to `Edit > Project Settings > XR Plug-in Management`
- Choose `Android` or `iOS`
- Enable respectively `ARCore` or `ARKit`

Be sure that you have already installed AR packages from the Unity Hub app (tested on Unity version 2021.3)

More infos here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/black-screen-unity-ar-camera-not-working.905972/

Answer (score 0):

I am stilling facing the black screen with Unity 2021.3.1f1
Done everything I can; including above.
Black screen...

AR Packages 4.2.2
XR Interaction 2.01
XR Management 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I followed the guidance in this guide, but I only work with **2021.3.1f1** and the packages listed below.

https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/configure-your-ar-development-environment?uv=2021.3&courseId=6346b7e5edbc2a7caec0f8fc&projectId=633b041bedbc2a6de5496294

[image]